# Haxe macro to set null to calling instance?

Tags: macros, haxe

Is there a way of setting a `null` to calling instance as a result of some "macro-function-call"?

Like so:

```
class A {
    // ...
    macro function DestroyItself() {
        // ...
    }
}

var a:A = new A();
// ...
a.DestroyItself();
trace(a); // "null"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep:

```
macro public function destroy(self:Expr) {
    return macro $self = null;
}
// ...
a.destroy();
```

In non-static macro functions first `Expr` argument is a ref to caller instance.

Comment: `macro public function destroy(self:haxe.macro.Expr) {...` **or** `import haxe.macro.Expr;`

Answer (score 3):

Once approach would be to create generic tools to `null` any instance.

```
package ;

class Tools
{
    /**
     *  Simply assigns null to the instance
     *  See more at: http://code.haxe.org/category/macros/generating-code-in-a-macro.html
     *  
     *  @param instance - Any
     *  @return haxe.macro.Expr
     */
    public static macro function nullMe(instance : haxe.macro.Expr.ExprOf<Dynamic>) : haxe.macro.Expr
    {
        return macro {
            ${instance} = null;
        };
    }
}
```

This use the `using Tools;` to generically `null` any instance, but I would **not** recommend this. I'd use the per-class approach.

**Main.hx**

```
package ;

class Main {

    static function main() {
        // Construct
        var instance = new SomeClass();

        // Destroy
        instance.destroy();

        // Trace null
        trace(instance);
    }
}
```

**SomeClass.hx**

```
package ;

class SomeClass
{
    public function new()
    {
        trace("Hello from SomeClass!");
    }

    private function preDestroy()
    {
        trace("The end is nigh!");
    }

    public macro function destroy(self : haxe.macro.Expr) : haxe.macro.Expr
    {
        return macro {
            @:privateAccess ${self}.preDestroy();
            ${self} = null;
        };
    }
}
```

**Compiled JS**

```
// Generated by Haxe 3.4.2
(function () { "use strict";
var Main = function() { };
Main.main = function() {
    var instance = new SomeClass();
    instance.preDestroy();
    instance = null;
    console.log(instance);
};
var SomeClass = function() {
    console.log("Hello from SomeClass!");
};
SomeClass.prototype = {
    preDestroy: function() {
        console.log("The end is nigh!");
    }
};
Main.main();
})();
```

Comment: At `@:privateAccess ${self}.preDestroy();` is it possible to check if the class has the `preDestroy` function?

Comment: It should be straight forward enough, but I don't think you'll need it as the destroy macro is implemented on the class. So it's safe to assume it will be there.

Comment: I would be careful when using this kind of solution. It might lead to "difficult to read" code. When destroying things, nulling the reference(s) is the last step. Then there's the fact that nulling a local variable would be useless.